# Balloon tethering cable tension model (catenary tether)

Tags: forces, experimental-physics, models

If a moving balloon (let's say it's a blimp system with some rotors for movement) is connected to the ground by a cable that describes a catenary curve, how can we model the tension being applied on the blimp by the cable?

[image: MSpaint draft]

This force has a vertical component that will be related to the mass of the cable and a horizontal component with the opposite direction of the movement of the blimp. Is there any model for this kind of behavior?